# How to Set COMPOSER_HOME on my machine? I have credentials for COMPOSER_AUTH

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I am installing a magento setup for my machine, in the quick start guide there is a requirement to set a COMPOSER_HOME, with the following command:

```
export COMPOSER_AUTH='{"http-basic":{"repo.magento.com": {"username": "REPLACE_THIS", "password": "REPLACE_THIS"}}}'
```

Apparently, after I will be able to get a permission to the specific docker and environment to launch a dev-site.

There is no much information about this in other questions here, and I have never tried this before thus have no idea how to tackle this. I would appreciate any help, or suggestion about what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the information on how to generate/regenerate auth keys: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html